# Stopwatch MVVM Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

It is my first time working in xamarin forms, I am now trying to make an app for myself. In my app I made a timer in my view model, but the seconds only go to 59 and reset automatically to 0. Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this and How I can make a stop button and a reset button my view model?

```
    public class TimerPageViewModel : ViewModelBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        private string _stopWatchHours;
        private string _stopWatchMinutes;
        private string _stopWatchSeconds;
        public TimerPageViewModel(INavigationService navigationService)
            : base(navigationService)
        {
            Title = "Timer";
            Start = new Command(OnStartTimerExecute);
            Stop = new Command(OnStop);
            Reset = new Command(onReset);
            StopWatchHours = stopwatch.Elapsed.Hours.ToString();
            StopWatchMinutes = stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
            StopWatchSeconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
        }
        public string StopWatchHours
        {
            get { return _stopWatchHours; }
            set { _stopWatchHours = value; OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchHours"); }
        }
        public string StopWatchMinutes
        {
            get { return _stopWatchMinutes; }
            set { _stopWatchMinutes = value; OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchSeconds"); }
        }
        public string StopWatchSeconds
        {
            get { return _stopWatchSeconds; }
            set { _stopWatchSeconds = value; OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchSeconds"); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var changed = PropertyChanged;
            if (changed != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public ICommand Start { get; set; }
        public ICommand Stop { get; set; }
        public ICommand Reset { get; set; }
        private void OnStartTimerExecute()
        {
            stopwatch.Start();
            Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), () =>
            {
                StopWatchHours = stopwatch.Elapsed.Hours.ToString();
                StopWatchMinutes = stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes.ToString();
                StopWatchSeconds = stopwatch.Elapsed.Seconds.ToString();
                return true;
            });
        }
        private void OnStop()
        {
            stopwatch.Stop();
            stopwatch = null;
        }
        private void onReset()
        {
            stopwatch.Reset();
        }
    }
```

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false"
             x:Class="MyApp.Views.TimerPage"
             IconImageSource="timer_icon_2x.png"
             Title="{Binding Title}">

    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Label HorizontalOptions="Center" FontSize="45" TextColor="#00A8E8">
        <Label.FormattedText>
            <FormattedString>
                    <Span Text="{Binding StopWatchHours}"/>
                    <Span Text=":"/>
                    <Span Text="{Binding StopWatchMinutes}"/>
                    <Span Text=":"/>
                    <Span Text="{Binding StopWatchSeconds}"/>
                </FormattedString>
        </Label.FormattedText>
        </Label>
        <Button Command="{Binding Start}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Stop}"/>
        <Button Command="{Binding Reset}"/>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: "the seconds only go to 59 and reset automatically to 0" - isn't this the normal behavior of a stopwatch?  To Start/Stop you need to define commands in your VM and bind them - which you appear to already be doing, so I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: My apologies, I mean after my 59 seconds the minutes are still at 0. normally after 59 seconds the minute sprints to 1, but in this case it doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are raising `OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchSeconds");` instead of `OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchMinutes");`

```
public string StopWatchMinutes
    {
        get { return _stopWatchMinutes; }
        set { _stopWatchMinutes = value; 
              OnPropertyChanged("StopWatchSeconds");
        }
    }
```